# Can't create or see Windows 7 restore points anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, environment-variables, path

Long story short, I was deleting some path variable in the Environment variable > system variable > path. I needed to clean up some path variables for my python. Have done something like this before, without issues. Though it may have been causing the following issues (although I am not 100% sure if it is the cause since I have been trying to setup anaconda and ipython notebook which might be the cause?). I haven't saved a copy of the path variable before deleting some paths (I know it was a bad idea, but I did that many times before and didn't have issues, didn't think anything bad could happen).

Now when I try to open or create a restore point it shows the "no restore points have been created..." error. And there is no way for me to create one either. Specifically, "The Volume Shadow Copy service used by System Restore is not working. For more informationview the event log. (0x81000202)."

I then tried going to "services" and it automatically pops up "an error has occurred..."

Can someone let me know what might be the problem and how to fix it.

I have since tried http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/error-volume-shadow-copy-service-used-by-system/bdfcd750-46ae-491d-b216-be4cf9e8929b?auth=1 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833. The first still gave me the same error. The latter says I have no problem 100%.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: sort of lame but https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/windows-update-issues/en-hk can patch up the enviroment path stuff, not much better than finding the string on the web.  and SFC /ScanNow could check for system file integrity.Leaving what could be some regitry pointers or something.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Did try SFC, no problem found.